# How to uncheck checkbox using tag value of another checkbox in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a **number of check boxes creating dynamically**.

Now i just want to **select any of them not more than one**. When i select the second one the first one should unselect.

I can't use radio group. Any help

Here is my code .. i am creating check boxes dynamically

private void createRadioButton() {
        cb = new CheckBox(fContext);

```
    cb.setTag(id++);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
             Log.i("comVisa","getPos =="+getPosition);

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code so that we can know what is your objective.

Comment: @Kris You want to use radio buttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: you mean Radio groups.actually i am coding for a crossplatform app i tried it but it is not working properly. then i decided to use checkbx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save last check box checked and unchecked it when checked other one like this

In public area define this

```
HashMap<String, CompoundButton> hash = new HashMap<String, CompoundButton>();
```

then edit your code :

```
cb.setTag(id++);

cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
     //int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
     if(isChecked){
         if(hash.size()>0){
                hash.get("1").setChecked(false);
             }
             hash.put("1", buttonView);


 }else{
hash.clear();
}
     Log.i("comVisa","getPos =="+getPosition);

}
});
```

Comment: I edited answer. Because when check then uncheck same CheckBox not work. Now it's work.

Answer (score 1):

A really simple example of using single selection checkbox.
 try this [link](http://www.mrsaqib.com/2011/12/allow-single-selection-on-android-checkbox/)

```
CheckBox myCheckBox[] = new CheckBox[noofCheckBox];
    for (int i=0; i<noofCheckBox; i++) {
        myCheckBox[i] = new myCheckBox(this);
        myCheckBox[i].setId(i+1);
        myCheckBox[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
             if(myCheckBox[i].getId() == getPosition){
                myCheckBox[i].setChecked(true);
             }else{
               myCheckBox[i].setChecked(false)
             }

        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: the link shows different checkboxes . it is easy to check and uncheck with those. here i am creating 50 check boxes for example with different tag .

Comment: you are creating using for loop?